# trying to install amd drivers

Tags: amd-graphics

I have linux mint mate 17 and am trying to install my amd drivers.
I downloaded my drivers from linux amd which gives me a .zip file, after extracting I get a .run file. If i run the .run file as is it seems to go fine till it reaches a point that it wants Superuser and reverts back, if I run it as admin I get:

```
    xed has not been able to detect the character encoding.
    Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
    Select a character encoding from the menu and try again.
```

I have tried both x32 and x64 for Ubuntu and linux OS and I always get the same result.
Is this a binary file? How do I get these drivers to install?

This is my video card:

```
    VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: https://mintguide.org/system/461-install-latest-amd-catalyst-driver-into-linux-mint.html http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Linux_Mint

Comment: tried both with no luck, themintguide one came close but it said i was missing tools required to install

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Driver Manager from Linux Mint Mate Control Panel?
This worked for me in Linux Mint Cinnamon. But this option is also available in Mate.